# Want these tables to calculate and check if and only if the button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I want the JavaScript code to be executed if I press the calculate and check button on top of each table. The results should be checked and calculated when I click the button on top of each table. I guess the problem mighty be the keyuphandler but I don't know how to get rid of it to get exactly what I want.

```js
const reducer = (a, c) => a + c;
const average = (n) => parseFloat(n.value) / 2 || 0;

const keyuphandler = (e) => {
  if (e.target instanceof HTMLInputElement && e.target.type == 'text') {

    let table = e.target.closest('table');
    let tr = e.target.closest('tr');

    let group = tr.dataset.group;
    let elem = e.target.dataset.elem;

    let result = table.querySelector(`tr[data-group="${group}"] input[data-elem="${elem}"].result`);
    let inputs = table.querySelectorAll(`tr[data-group="${group}"] input[data-elem="${elem}"].input`);

    // Calculate the average
    result.value = [...inputs]
      .map(average)
      .reduce(reducer, 0);

    // Check if the difference between input1 and input2 
    // is greater than 0.3
    if (elem === 'carbon' && group === '1') {
      const input1 = parseFloat(inputs[0].value);
      const input2 = parseFloat(inputs[1].value);
      const difference = Math.abs(input1 - input2);
      if (difference > 0.3) {
        alert("NOT REPEATABLE.");
      }
    }
  }
};

document.addEventListener('keyup', keyuphandler);
```

```css
table {
  width: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-family: monospace
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 10px;
}

th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0px;
}

table {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: monospace
}

td,
th {
  padding: 0.25rem;
}

[data-elem='carbon'] {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 100, 0.1)
}

[data-elem='sulphur'] {
  background: rgba(0, 100, 0, 0.1)
}

[readonly] {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1)
}

.input {
  width: 3rem
}

.result {
  width: 3.5rem
}

input {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 0.2rem;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>%<br />Carbon</th>
    <th>Average<br />Carbon</th>
  </tr>
  <tr data-group="1">
    <td><input type="text" class="input" data-elem="carbon" data-input="1" placeholder="input1" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="input" data-elem="carbon" data-input="2" placeholder="input2" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="result" data-elem="carbon" readonly placeholder="average" /></td>
  </tr>
  <button onclick="calculateAndCheckDifference()">Calculate and Check</button>
</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>%<br />Carbon</th>
    <th>Average<br />Carbon</th>
  </tr>
  <tr data-group="1">
    <td><input type="text" class="input" data-elem="carbon" data-input="1" placeholder="input1" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="input" data-elem="carbon" data-input="2" placeholder="input2" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="result" data-elem="carbon" readonly placeholder="average" /></td>
  </tr>
  <button onclick="calculateAndCheckDifference()">Calculate and Check</button>
</table>
```

Comment: Your code doesn't have a `calculateAndCheckDifference()` method defined anywhere.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I am still a beginner in javascript and i am trying to get sulphur and carbon average results from text inputs by users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76760187/i-am-still-a-beginner-in-javascript-and-i-am-trying-to-get-sulphur-and-carbon-av)